# Spring Boot: Entity Field '' doesn't have a default value when persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is my Alert Entity class, I am generating the ID automatically. But at saving, I get the error as Spring Boot: Entity Field 'u_id' doesn't have a default value. I tried strategy = SEQUENCE/AUTO as well, same result.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Alert {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "u_id")
    private long u_id = 1;
    @Embedded
    private Reading reading;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    String vin;

    private String priority;

    public long getU_id() {
        return u_id;
    }

    public void setU_id(long u_id) {
        this.u_id = u_id;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }


    public Reading getVehicleReading() {
        return reading;
    }

    public void setVehicleReading(Reading vehicleReading) {
        this.reading = vehicleReading;
        this.vin = vehicleReading.getVin();
    }


}
```

Comment: Is the `=1` in `private long u_id = 1;` a typo?  This will make all new instances of this object have the same ID, which could result in unintentional updates where you want to do an insert.

Comment: not exactly, it made made it to set 1 as default value. I now changed the code to 
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "u_id", columnDefinition="NUMBER(10) default '1'")
    private int u_id;

Now I get a Error executing DDL

Comment: Either way, this sounds like it may be a problem with the database schema.  Did you use Hibernate to generate the schema or did you do it manually?  You may want to check on your database server that the column is set to be an auto increment or identify column (depends on what database you're using)

Comment: @aelfric5578 Thanks a lot! was struggling with this from 4 hours. The AUTO increment was not being set for some reason. I had to provide another annotation as well. @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial").

Answer (score 0):

Providing another annotation as below solved it.

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
```